# How to mock a method inside a method I'm testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class RequestProcessor with a method:

```
   public ResponseClass process(Request request) {
       String requestId = requestService.saveRequest(request);
       ResponseClass response = new Response();
       response.setId(requestId);
       return response;
}
```

I need to write a test using Mockito, I came up with:

```
public class RequestProcessor {
    @InjectMocks
    private RequestProcess sut;
    @Mock
    private RequestService requestService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
    String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    
    Request request = new Request(); //then setting up values of request
    Mockito.when(requestService.saveRequest(request).thenReturn(requestId);
    ResponseClass response = sut.process(request);
    Assert.assertEquals(response.getRequestId(), requestId)
}
```

But the response.getRequestId() return null. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you print the request id in your process function - is it null?

Comment: @AsadAwadia, do you mean the result of sut.process()? Yes, it is null

Comment: Your code is confusing. The function has request service but your test has response service. Are you sure you are mocking the right thing?

Comment: @AsadAwadia thanks for noticing! I've edited the question, there's only one service class to mock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to a missing mock behaviour of **sut.process(request)**. Can you add the mock behaviour of **sut.process(request)** too?

```
public class RequestProcessor {
    @InjectMocks
    private RequestProcess sut;
    @Mock
    private RequestService requestService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
    String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    
    Request request = new Request(); //then setting up values of request
    Mockito.when(requestService.saveRequest(request).thenReturn(requestId);
    Mockito.when(sut.process(request).thenCallRealMethod();
    ResponseClass response = sut.process(request);
    Assert.assertEquals(response.getRequestId(), requestId)
}
```

Comment: now it tells me that "this.requestQueryClass" that is used in the constructor of requestService is null.

Comment: Can you try @Mock instead of @InjectMocks?

Comment: yes, now it says that "this.requestService is null"

Comment: If want to use the default behaviour of the class, then you don't need to mock **RequestProcess**. Just create an instance of **RequestProcess** with the necessary data and dependent mock objects.

Comment: I found the mistake, it was on my side, but I'll accept your answer